# base64 package not available. Is there a substitute so I can use the command anyway?

Tags: linux, bash, base64, busybox

I am on a system where i can not install any packages and my busybox does not include the `base64` command. However I need to run a script that uses `base64` de/encoding. 
Is there a way to do that in a function in the script maybe?

Answer (score 2):

well, how easy it is to en/decode base64 really depends on what *is* installed on your system.

e.g. [openssl can encode and decode base64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/178521):

```
$ openssl enc -base64 <<< 'Hello, World!'
SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQo=
$ openssl enc -base64 -d <<< SGVsbG8sIFdvcmxkIQo=
Hello, World!
```

Comment: Unfortunately my System does not have openssl. Only `openssl_genrsa` and `openssl_req` (it's a fritzbox router)